# Better Excel shortcut for current time

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, keyboard-shortcuts

Is there a way I can set an easier shortcut for the current time in Excel? I know about "ctrl+shift+;" but I need something that can be used with one hand. Ideally if I could set up and F key to add the current time. that would be best.

Any possibilities or advice?

Thank you!

Comment: What is wrong with this shortcut? You can perform it with your right pinky on right `Ctrl`, your right ring finger on right `Shift` and your right index or middle finger on `;`. It might be a bit of a contortionist trick depending on your keyboard layout, but nothing impossible unless your semicolon is right in the center (which can be the case with Dvorak layouts).

Answer (score 1):

The easiest method is to record a macro where you do that keypress, and assign it to one of the F.. keys.

To do this, start recording a macro, press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>;</kbd>, then hit stop record, and assign it to a key, such as F11.

Now, every time you press F11, the time will be inserted in the current cell.

You can include things like formatting in the recording, and that will also be executed.

Do note, if you click on a cell after you start recording, that cell click will also be recorded. This means that if you click record, then click cell A5, then insert the time there, then stop record, then every time you run the macro, the time will be inserted into cell A5, regardless of which cell you had selected before.

Comment: I got the macro to save, however, it doesn't allow me to save it to an F key. It requires I choose a letter. How do I get around this?

Comment: Hmm, its possible Microsoft changed this. I currently do not have access to Microsoft Office, so I can't test it for you. It should still be possible though, but I have to look into it.

Comment: You may be able to find what you're looking for in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9818047/assign-keyboard-shortcut-to-run-procedure it has an answer that tells you how to change keyboard shortcuts currently in use. There must be one for Function keys too.

Answer (score 1):

Take this macro:

```
Sub Tyme()
    ActiveCell.Value = Now - Int(Now)
    ActiveCell.NumberFormat = "H:MM AM/PM"
End Sub
```

and assign a shortcut key to it. I usually use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd>

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Save a macro like this. You can assign a shortcut to your macro.

To save a macro;
Press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F11</kbd>
Add a new module
paste the code below into the text area

```
Sub Macro1()
    With ActiveCell
        .FormulaR1C1 = Now()
        .NumberFormat = "h:mm AM/PM"
    End With
End Sub
```

To assign a shortcut, under **DEVELOPER** tab, click **Macros**, select your macro and click **Options**

Comment: -1 because there is a difference between using the =Now() function and inserting the time using CTRL+SHIFT+;. The heyboard combination inserts the current time/date as text and it doesn't change upon a recalculation.